# Simple Ajax in asp.net MVC 3, update the model and rerender part

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I come from a more `WPF` application background and I'm used to bindings and such. Jumping into websites then can come with it's problems as they work so much more differently.

I'm trying to do a simple `Ajax` action but not sure where to begin. Basically I want to make a dropdownlist that changes one property on the model and re-renders that part of the page. Perhaps this is too much of a WPF way to do this so my Model could be twisted for the thing it is supposed to do.

Here is what I got already:

```
public class TheViewModel
{
    private IEnumerable<TheData> _data;

    public TheViewModel(IEnumerable<TheData> data)
    {
        _data = data;
        Year = 2012;
    }

    public int Year { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TheData> Data
    {
        get
        {
            return _data.Where(d => d.Year == this.Year).ToList();
        }
    }

     public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> YearList
     {
        // lists the available years
     }
}

public class TheData
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    //Some more info I want to represent in Table
}
```

And the razor:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "thetable" }))
{
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Year, Model.YearList, new { AutoPostBack = "true"})
        <input type="submit" name="name" value="Submit" />
}


<table id="thetable">
    <thead>
        //some headers
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach ( var item in Model.Data)
    {
        //row for each data
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see I'm hoping for the Year property to be updated and a new call to be made for the Data property which would result in new information. That information would be rendered in `thetable` Table

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a full example.

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Years
    {
        get
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1980, 40).Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.ToString(),
                Text = x.ToString()
            });
        }
    }

    public IList<TheData> Data { get; set; }
}

public class TheData
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(int year)
    {
        var model = new[]
        {
            new TheData { Year = year, Foo = "foo 1", Bar = "bar 1" },
            new TheData { Year = year, Foo = "foo 2", Bar = "bar 2" },
            new TheData { Year = year, Foo = "foo 3", Bar = "bar 3" },
        };
        return PartialView("_data", model);
    }
}
```

`Index.cshtml` view:

```
@model MyViewModel

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#yearsddl').change(function () {
            $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
        });
    });
</script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "data" }))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Year, Model.Years, new { id = "yearsddl" })
}

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Foo</th>
            <th>Bar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="data">
        @Html.Partial("_data", Model.Data ?? Enumerable.Empty<TheData>())
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script inclusion should be moved out of the index view inside the layout for example and the custom js that subscribes for the change event of the dropdownlist should be moved into a separate js file and included from the Layout. I just put them here to illustrate a full example of what's required for the view to work.

`_Data.cshtml` partial:

```
@model IList<TheData>

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Year)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Foo)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Bar)</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you, this is what I needed. As of your solution I decided to seperate it into 2 models with information outside the update in one and the updatable in another. Problem there is setting the default data. Html.Partial would mean I would have to include the other viewmodel with default setting in the other one. So I was hoping I could just call Html.Action instead but not sure how to make it call the post action instead of get.

Comment: Well another problem is that the DropDownList is forced to be inside the partialView because of styling. It works the first time but not again.

Comment: @IngóVals, in this case you should use `.delegate` or `.on (in jQuery 1.7+) instead of `.change` to subscribe to the change event of the dropdown list if this ddl is added subsequently in the DOM using AJAX for example.

Comment: hmm Delegate doesn't seem to work. $(function () {
        $('#yearsddl').delegate(function () {
            $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
        });
Not really good at js
    });

Comment: @IngóVals, you are not using it correctly. You never specified the event you are willing to subscribe to. Take a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/). You may try: `$(document).delegate('#yearsddl', 'change', function() { $(this).closest('form').submit(); });`. Also to make the selector even more performant you could use `$('form')` instead of `$(document)`. I strongly suggest you going through the documentation of jQuery and doing some getting started tutorials if you intend to use it in your web applications.

Comment: Nevermind, I found out how to work the delegate
    $(function () {
        $('body').delegate('#yearsddl', 'change', function () {
            $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
        });
    });