# update a partial view using ajax and add elements to it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I'm using ASP.Net MVC 4 (C#, Entity Framework Code First) and am in a need to have a table where the user clicks on an add button and I add a product to the list (table) for this I looked everywhere and finally found the following example here:

[Simple Ajax in asp.net MVC 3, update the model and rerender part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465475/simple-ajax-in-asp-net-mvc-3-update-the-model-and-rerender-part)

I got it to work just fine but I can't seem to get the current list (whatever is in IList in the example above) to get sent back to the action to add new rows to it. how can I do this?

I've tried to use the convention `name="TheData[1].foo"` for example and accept `List<TheData>` as a parameter to the action and nothing seems to be working.

Comment: It's always best to post what you have not unless your code looks exactly the same as what Darin gave over there.

Comment: @vonv. it honestly does at this point. just the class names and properties are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I just needed to include `@Html.HiddenFor(...`s for all of the values, I don't know how I missed that but that was the problem. once added it all posted back just fine.